# Reading from Pivot Table excel

Tags: c#-4.0, closedxml

Read data from a excel sheet containing pivot table using closedxml. When trying to read it's cell values are empty.

Comment: ClosedXML doesn't support this yet.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha Do you think is there any other way for this?